# How to fix not re-rendering issue after updating state using a generic function

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, render

I am trying to update the property particular property of my state using  a common function, which will take current state, property name and property new value as parameter and returns state with updated value for the property. But my react component is not re-rendering with the updated value. What exactly I am doing wrong here?

Using chrome developer tools when I have checked the new state object it has updated value, but my react component rendering function is not getting invoked again

following is code snippet written in my `reducer` for updating the function:

```
function App(state = initialState, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ON_CHANGE:
      let newState = Utilities.updateProperty(
        state,
        action.change.key,
        action.change.value
      );
      return newState;
    case DIFFERENT_ACTION:
      // TODO implementation
      return state;
    default:
      return initialState;
  }
}
```

And following is the code written in `Utilities.updateProperty` function:

```
updateProperty(object, key, value) {
    let keys = key.split(".");
    let obj = object;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
      obj = obj[keys[i]];
    }
    obj[keys[keys.length - 1]] = value;
    return object;
}
```

When I added a break point at line where `return newState;` written, I can see that value is perfectly updated here. So I was expecting my component will re-render with new value.

If I change my `return newState` as below its working properly:

```
return {
  ...newState,
  ...{
    now: new Date()
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first spread your state so it becomes a new object

```
updateProperty(object, key, value) {
    let keys = key.split(".");
    let obj = { ...object }; // let obj = object;
    for (var i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
      obj = obj[keys[i]];
    }
    obj[keys[keys.length - 1]] = value;
    return obj; // return object;
}
```

Comment: This worked as expected. Thank you. Can please provide some explanation around this, why it has to be a new object why its not working with the existing one.

Comment: that will work for a key with a single part, but this is designed to work with dotted keys. Pretty sure he'll need to destructure the object for each step. ie `obj = {...obj[keys[i]]}`. I'd suggest combining `immer` and `lodash.set` to make things much simpler.

Comment: @PiccazaDe Basically redux checks to see if the state changed by matching it with the identity operator `===` against the previous state object. If you mutate your state object by changing its inner values like `state[key] = val` the state object itself still has the same identity (address in memory) so redux does not know that the state changed. As pointed out by lecstor you'll also need to spread your inner objects if they're not primitives, so your utility function will not work in all cases.

Comment: @Eugene Okay, I am understanding this now. So in that case once I update this code `let obj = { ...object };` I don't have to change this `obj = {...obj[keys[i]]}` right, as obj is already a new object with reference to new address memory, so even if I change inner level values also it will work perfectly.  Is that correct?

Comment: @PiccazaDe not in all cases, as soon as `obj[keys[i]]` contains a nested object like `user: { contacts: [abc] }` only `user` object will be spread with this approach and if any of your components consumes `contacts` property directly they'll need to be spread as well to be fed as an update to components by redux.

Comment: I would suggest to try writing your reducers by hand at first instead of creating a catch-all utility method so you have a better understanding of how reducers work and which parts of state need to be spread at which point. When you spread a certain object, the objects that it contains within it are not deep copied and are simply referenced by the newly spread object.

Comment: definitely agree that you should should avoid this sort of generic reducer whenever possible as it negates much of the organisational benefits of using redux in the first place.

Comment: @Eugene `When you spread a certain object, the objects that it contains within it are not deep copied and are simply referenced by the newly spread object.` - got it thanks.

Comment: @lecstor I didn't get you exactly.

Comment: I have update the answer to make sure to work in my scenario. I want the function to return whole updated object instead of final key value.

Comment: @PiccazaDe I just mean that ideally an action/reducer will describe a specific change to your store. Depending on the use of your generic reducer it could well make it much harder to debug issues if a bad change could have come from any use of the reducer in your code and it makes the action logging in dev-tools less useful.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with something like this that will cover all the bases (untested).

```
import produce from "immer";
import set from "lodash.set";

updateProperty(object, key, value) {
  return produce(object, draft => set(draft, key, value))
}
```

Comment: I should update code base with `lodash`, this is pretty clean and neat. Also no need to reinvent this wheels again.  Thank you.